# VB.net and MS access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am in the middle of the creation of an application using vb.net. I have a database created in MS.Access which includes 7 tables. I connected this one with my parent program code.

Now the problem is that I want to display the data from each column. I have 12 columns and 14 rows in my first table.  How can I display data from one column in a Combo box?

Can anybody explain with program code?

Comment: May be of interest: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1618500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim cmAs New OleDbCommand("Select DISTINCT "Columnname" from Table1", cn)
da= New OleDbDataAdapter(cm)

If (ds.Tables.Contains("Table1") = False) Then
    da.Fill(ds, "Table1")
End If

With cboComboBox
    .DataSource = ds.Tables("Table1")
    .DisplayMember = "Columnname"
    .ValueMember = "Columnname"
End With
```

I hope this helps u along the way, i found this code myself after a hard searchin period :P
i hope im not to late for your question...

Comment: Thank for your valuable reply, I got it before you answered. Sorry for the delay. Keep helping.